# Tkinter how to set icon and images for other users

Tags: python, tkinter

I developed small app using Tkinter Gui. I set icon and background image by specifying the path on my machine but when I send .exe file to someone else icon and image paths gives error because it is not on their machine locally. How should I deal with that so that other users can see icon and images without having it locally?

Comment: You can pack the icon and image file into the .exe file. Refer to the document of the generation tool.

Comment: i use pyinstaller.

Comment: Refer PyInstaller [document](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#what-to-bundle-where-to-search) on including files in the executable.

Comment: i have done it already. othwerwise wouldnt post it here